# Type 'User' has no subscript members

Tags: ios, swift, types

I'm new to Swift and worried I'm defining my variables incorrectly here. I'm sure it's a dumb mistake I'm making because I'm not totally understanding Swift syntax.

I am getting the error that my User type doesn't have any subscript members when I'm referencing them in a function:

```
    let item = userDataSource[indexPath.row]
    cell.leftLabel.text = item[0]
    cell.rightLabel.text = item[1]
```

However, I am extending

```
extension AccountViewController: GetUserDelegate {
    func getUserSuccess(user: User) {
        self.userDataSource = [user]
    }
}
```

And userDataSource is defined at the top of the class:

```
fileprivate var userDataSource: [User]
```

Am I not casting my variables correctly? The User model is just a mapped JSON obj:

```
guard let user = Mapper<User>().map(JSONObject: value)
```

What am I missing here? Am I correct in that I am casting my variables incorrectly?

This is ultimately how I'd like the array to look:

```
    ["Name", "Bob Jim"],
    ["MC #", "1234567"],
    ["Company Name", "Bob's Truckin"],
    ["Truck Type", "Flat Bed"],
    ["Cell", "(555) 555-5555"],
    ["Dispatch", "(999) 999-9999"],
    ["Favorite Destinations", "Los Angeles"]
```

Comment: Two questions. 1: If I've understood your question correctly, u have a `User` class and an array called `userDataSource` which is outside your class that is meant to hold all of your users correct? 2: What is the delegate for exactly?

Comment: I have a user class, and I want to have a userDataSource which is an array of properties with the name of the user item as as the 0 index and the value as 1 index. I didn't write this portion of the code, so I'm not quite sure why the delegate was written in.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want `userData[0]` to give you `User.name` then `userData[1]` to give you `User.value`? And what exactly is _value_ then?

Comment: No no, I want userData[0] to give me the value of the property name and userData[1] to give me the value of that property. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I've already realized, I think, that I need to convert the user object into an array.

Comment: I am trying to do this: fileprivate var userDataSource = Array<String>(User), but this is throwing an error that I am not conforming to the expected type sequence. Is there a way to cast an ObjectMapper mapped object to an array like I am trying?

Comment: I sent you a chat request. Here's the [link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166553/room-for-eshirima-and-andrew-alexander)

Answer (score 0):

Your **userDataSource** is an array of users like you mentioned.

```
fileprivate var userDataSource: [User]
```

You'll get back an user of any specified index by

```
let item = userDataSource[indexPath.row] as User
```

Here, **item** is user object which has no subscript member, if you use **item[0].**

you should use something like below:

```
item.name // or any property 
or
cell.leftLabel.text = item.name
```

Comment: Hrm, my protocol is only returning one user, so it appears I'm wrapping it in an array unnecessarily. All I'm wanting is to get one user down to the cell.leftLabel area, with the properties separated as name|value per each array row.

Comment: Sorry if my understanding is a bit low of how this is all working - I've only worked on one small Swift project before this.